# Combine rows per groups in R (or Stata)

Tags: r, networking, dataset, stata, igraph

I have an issue in R (or Stata) which I cannot solve. I have a database as the sample below:

| Year | ID | Firm | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2000 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2000 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2000 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 2000 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 2000 | 6 | 3 | 3 |
|  |  |  |  |
| 2001 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2001 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 2001 | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 2001 | 4 | 2 | 5 |
| 2001 | 5 | 2 | 5 |
| 2001 | 6 | 3 | 6 |

I would need to have a list of interactions of IDs within the same group (i.e.: working at the same firm in a given year) for a network analysis.
Something like the following:

| Year | ID | Firm | Group | Interactions_A | Interactions_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2000 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2000 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2000 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 2000 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 6 |  |
| 2000 | 6 | 3 | 3 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2001 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 2001 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 2001 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 2001 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 5 |
| 2001 | 5 | 2 | 5 | 6 |  |
| 2001 | 6 | 3 | 6 |  |  |

Are there any suggestions to do this in R (can also be in Stata)?

Thanks a lot for your kind help!

Comment: With dplyr, `left_join(x,x, by = c("Firm", "Year")` will give you a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R you can first get all the combinations between IDs of each group, and then format the data to get one column for each node.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(new = ifelse(n() > 1, paste(combn(ID, 2), collapse = "-"), as.character(ID))) %>% 
  separate_rows(new, sep = "(?:[^-]*(?:-[^-]*){1})\\K-") %>% 
  separate(new, into = c("Interactions_A", "Interactions_B"))

   Group Interactions_A Interactions_B
   <int> <chr>          <chr>         
 1     1 1              2             
 2     2 3              4             
 3     2 3              5             
 4     2 4              5             
 5     3 6              NA            
 6     4 1              2             
 7     4 1              3             
 8     4 2              3             
 9     5 4              5             
10     6 6              NA
```

data

```r
dat <- read.table(header= T, text = "Year   ID  Firm    Group
2000    1   1   1
2000    2   1   1
2000    3   2   2
2000    4   2   2
2000    5   2   2
2000    6   3   3
2001    1   1   4
2001    2   1   4
2001    3   1   4
2001    4   2   5
2001    5   2   5
2001    6   3   6")
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind help! You're great, the solution seems exactly what I need. I'm now trying with a large dataset which is taking a long time as expected. I get the error message "result would exceed 2^31-1 bytes". I'll try to figure it out maybe with smaller datasets but it should work as in the sample. Many thanks!

Comment: With larger groups, the number of combinations grows exponentially, so you rapidly get too much rows. This may mean it is not the right approach.

Comment: Exactly, you're right. The solution is exactly what I need but unfortunately it seems to not be possible in very large datasets. Thanks again!